# SQlite Language based table selection

Tags: android, sqlite

just for curious, i got a question!

My app is almost ready.. I have implemented bilingual (English/Tamil) when users select thr preferred language in Settings then whole app gets converted into that language (i used custom Locale). Everything works fine.

My question is, Can we do the same to SQlite database? which fetch data automatically based on locale from table
"country-en"or"country-ta" ? is there any way? i heard that thr is a method SQLiteOpenHelper.onConfigure(setLocale()); to set locale in sqlitedatabase. i want to know how it works!

Comment: Of course, yes, **you can**. When you do your queries just append "en" or "ta" ("SELECT FROM Country_" + yourLocale + "...") if you want to use two different tables. OR you could use **one single table** with an integer field "Language" and you pass an int (0 = english, 1 = tamil - only for alphabetical order, which is easier to remind)... ("... WHERE ... AND Language = 0").

Comment: Thanks alot!! it really helped me :-) btw.. post it as an answer so that i can give thumbs up fr yu :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, yes, you can.

When you do your queries, just append "en" or "ta".
Something like "SELECT FROM Country_" + yourLocale + "..." - if you want to use two different tables.

OR you could use one single table with an integer field "Language" and you pass an int (0 = english, 1 = tamil - only for alphabetical order, which is easier to remind)...

Something like "... WHERE ... AND Language = 0"

Answer (score 4):

The method you describe above is not related to language localization for the client. It's related to locale options on the database (for example how to treat string comparisons with accented characters).

Anyway, if you think of it... what does localizing a database mean? You can either localize the structure or the data. Localizing the structure (table names...) doesn't make sens because the user is not aware of it. Localizing the data doesn't make sense either, because that means that if the users changes language settings, next time he uses your app he won't see his data!

If the DB only contains static data and you need to provide a different DB for different languages, you could use localization to lookup for the database filename.

Comment: Thank you Merlevede for explaining :-)